# Bluetooth connection via HID/HSP profiles (Smartphone/PWA to IoT device)

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, progressive-web-apps, hid, connectivity

Bluetooth connection via *HID/HSP* profiles (*Smartphone/PWA* to IoT device)

We are developing an IoT device and face issues with automatic connectivity to the smartphone via *Bluetooth*, as we have to use a *PWA* instead of a native app.
We consider using a standard profile (e.g. Headset Profile (HSP), Human Interface Device Profile (HID))  to enable communication via *Bluetooth* between device and *PWA*.

We now require a workaround for the following issue:

When using *HSP/HID*, existing connections to the smartphone's hardware (e.g. headset, keyboard) can be interrupted.

Have you faced similar issues and do you know workarounds for this?

Are you knowledgeable about alternative connection mechanisms (e.g. NFC, SIM) to connect IoT with *PWA* incl. pros and cons?